# Too many requests to Custom Adapter GetView. Is this ussual?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a custom adapter that just draws some text items (every item have just one textview).

In my tests I have added 3 items to the adapter but the system is calling 9 times (the list items are requested 3 times) GetView for the adapter before everything is displayed. Is this ussual? Shouldn't the sytem just call 3 times to GetView to draw the full list?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would like to see you adapters code and how you use it in your activity/fragment.

Comment: The problem is that my code are not simple adapters. I have a little system to create lists of heterogeneous items pretty easily but I can't show it because of NDA. Anyway digging a bit more I have suffered from this problems like this too. It seems it is how android works. I understand you could not guess what happens without taking a look to the code, but what I really would like to know is if people have found this problem in their own code with simple adapters.